# CMake looks for Visual Studio BuildTools while I have Professional edition installed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2019

Some time ago, I installed "Visual Studio 2019 BuildTools" to test the new compiler. Now, I deinstalled it and installed "Visual Studio 2019" (full).

"Visual Studio 2019" is correctly installed as I'm able to generate a hello world using the IDE.

However, when I run `CMake` from a shell (or even from Visual Studio 2019 command prompt), it fails to find Visual Studio 2019 compiler and reports:

```
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:243 (project):
  Generator

    Visual Studio 16 2019

  could not find specified instance of Visual Studio:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools
```

My computer does not have a `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools` folder, however `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild` exist...

Looks like VS 2019 BuildTools uninstallation went wrong and things are messed up. Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: Note: I reinstalled BuildTools and now it works. But this should not be required to configure a project when Visual Studio Professional is installed.

Answer (score 1):

You could open `Tools->Get Tools and Features->Visual Studio Installer`.

1. Check if `Desktop development with C++`
   [image]

2.Check if `Visual Studio extension development`
[image]

3. Click `Individual Component` to check whether the following components are installed

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

4.Check the environment variables whether there are the following two environment variables.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. All those components were installed and the environment variables are set.

Comment: I suggest that you could try to install the latest version of cmake.